# InternalError when deploying to ECS using CodePipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-s3

I'm trying to deploy to ECS using AWS CodePipeline. Source and build stages are working fine, but deploy stage shows an error:

> JobFailed: Internal Error

If I deploy my project to my ECS cluster manually, it works properly. CodePipeline role has all the needed permissions.

I don't know even how to check what is happening.

According [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_en/codepipeline/latest/userguide/troubleshooting.html#troubleshooting-reg-1), it could be because S3 bucket is stored in another region, different from the pipeline's region. But, in my case, both are in London.

Comment: Hi Héctor, if the response below helped resolve your question please upvote and accept it. That's the ServerFault's way to say thank you for the time and effort someone took to help you. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things to check:

- **CloudWatch logs** - they may provide further details.
- **CodePipeline permissions** - I know you say it's got all the needed permission but for testing give it *AdministratorAccess* and test with that.